# What does it mean when someone says a discussion section is not "well-developed"?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

A reviewer of my paper told me that the discussion section is not well developed.

What does this mean? What should I work on to improve my discussion section?

Comment: Saying something is not well developed indicates that you need to put more thought into it. You are probably missing some content that the reviewer expected to see. Look at other people's discussions for ideas of what might be missing. Furthermore, you should make sure all your statements are backed up or fully explained.

Comment: Maybe the structure of your discussion is not good. Novice writers have a tendency to write in the style of a "brain dump". A brain dump is surely okay for a first draft, but from then, you need to edit your draft so that it becomes appealing to the reader. The first paragraph should broadly summarize what the different points in the section will be, and how they are connected together. From then you need to present the points clearly, in a logical order, and giving each of them about the same amount of space.

Comment: If the discussion in the original paper had the same level of english as was shown in the original title and question then that may partly explain the reviewer’s comments, so improving the discussion would likely be the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the reviewer says the Discussion section is not well developed, it suggests you either need to cover more of the elements that go there or go into greater depth on the things you do say there.

[Carnegie Mellon has a nice handout](https://www.cmu.edu/gcc/handouts/imrd-examples-pdf) about what different traditional elements of a paper should contain.

> Discussion sections contain the following moves:
>
> 1. They summarize the main findings of the study.  This allows readers to skip to the beginning of the 
>      discussion section and understand the main “news” in the report.
> 2. They connect these findings to other research
> 3. They discuss flaws in the current study.
> 4. They use these flaws as reasons to suggest additional, future research.
> 5. (If needed) They state the implications of their findings for future policy or practice.

Further, if the Results section does not comment on the results, such as attempting to explain them and evaluating whether the results support the hypothesis, then that should be part of the Discussion.

Finally, as henning recommends, let a trusted colleague read the paper and ask for their suggestions for improving the discussion section.

Comment: I was writing a similar answer, but I prefer yours. I would only like to add my recommendation to let a trusted colleague read the paper and ask him or her for suggestions to improve the section.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar comment from and editor (who desk rejected a paper) saying that I needed to 'develop my concepts further' without elaborating further. I take such advice to mean I need to add more meat and refine how my concept advances my argument and how the concept can travel to other empirical cases.